# Firebase: query data that has subkey

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database:

```
  users
    + 34534
    + 00123
      company: "Foo2"
    - 04521
      - actions
        - LELgkJG-4ETy3G480ru
          timestamp: 1528315440019
          type: "QRCODE"
        - LELgkJG-4ETy3G480ru
          timestamp: 1528315440000
      company: "Foo"
    + 12345
```

So that each users identified by a key, and each user has an array of actions.

So that user `00123` has no actions instead user `04521` has actions.

I'd like to query all user that has at least one action. Is it possible? Do I need to de-normalize my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Database can order/filter on a single property that is at a known path under each child node of the location where you query. Since the individual actions are not at a known path, I don't think you can query for them.

The simplest way to get the result you want, would be to add an `actionCount` property to each user and keep that up to date and update that as you add/remove actions. That way you can query for users with actions with:

```
firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild("actionCount").startAt(1)
```

Comment: thanks @Frank van Puffelen I'm reading a lot of your answer in SO, there is a lot to learn. I will wait to accept the anser anyway a few days. Thanks!